# Given V =$(x_1,x_2......., x_{100}) $ with conditions. Find dim (V)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V =$(x_1,x_2......., x_{100}) \in R^{100}$ 
such that

$ x_1=2x_2=3x_3$ and

$x_{51}-x_{52}-.....-x_{100}=0$

Then find dimension of V.

I am having problem with quickly determining dimension in these sort of problems .one way is to find number of free variables, but they are sort of hard to see here. Is there a efficient way to deal with such  problems??
Answer is 97

Comment: You need more conditions to find the precise dimension! All the vectors might be $0$, but the dimension may also be as high as $97$.

Comment: @JensBoldsen how could u see it quickly that it is 97?

Comment: Let $x_1,x_4,x_5,x_6,\dots,x_{99}$ be $97$ linear independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{100}$, the conditions now give you the definitions of the missing three vectors $x_2,x_3,x_{100}$ which will depend linearly on the first $97$ vectors.

Comment: @JensBoldsen I think $x_1$ is the first component of the vector that is in $V$...

Comment: Sorry, I have misread the question.

Comment: You have to decide, is $V$ a vector or a vector space?

Comment: I thought that $x_1,\dots x_{100}$ were all vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{100}$. Since $V$ is now just one vector the dimension if $V$ is either $1$ or $0$, unless you mean the dimension of the subspace containing all the vectors satisfying these conditions, then the answer is $97$, as shown in 5xum's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $V$ is the set of all vectors $x\in \mathbb R^{100}$ such that if $$x=[x_1,x_2,\dots, x_{100}],$$

then the two equations are satisfied.

In that case, the easiest way to show that the dimension of $V$ is to prove that $V$ is the nullspace of the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
1 & 0 & -3 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & \dots & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: So  rank of matrix is 3 and nullity is 97. But is there some other way also to approach this problem?

Comment: @User786 Of course there is. You can also fund the basis of $V$ and prove that it is both linearly independent and that it spans $V$. I only said that what I posted seems (at least to me) as the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem called Rank–nullity theorem. It says that, if $ T: E\to U $ is a linear transformation, then $ dim(Ker (T))+dim (Im (T)) = dim (dom (T)) $. Take a look at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

$ V $ is clearly the kernel of the linear transformation $ T: \mathbb{R}^{100}\to \mathbb{R}^3 $ defined by 
$ T(x_1, \ldots , x_ {100}) = ((x_1 - 2x_2), (x_1 - 3x_3), (x_{51}-x_{52}-\cdots -x_{100})) $

Observe that $T$ is surjective. Therefore $dim (V) + dim (\mathbb{R}^3) = dim (\mathbb{R} ^{100}) $. Hence $ dim (V) = 97 $.